# C++: Implicit Member Functions

Tags: c++

Consider below code which I have written:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Sample{
    int a;
    public:
    Sample(){a=0;cout << "Sample Created (Default Constructor)" << endl;}
    Sample(int n):a(n){cout << "Sample Created" << endl;}
    ~Sample(){ cout << "Sample destroyed" << endl;}
    Sample(Sample& s){a=s.getA(); cout << "Sample Copy Constructor called" << endl;}
    Sample& operator= (Sample& s){this->a=s.getA(); cout << "Assignment Operator Called" << endl;return (*this);}
    void setA(int n){ a=n;}
    int getA(){return a;}
    };

class Test{
    Sample k;
    public:
    Test(){ cout << "Test Created(Default Constructor)" << endl;}
    Test(Sample& S):k(S){ cout << "Test Created" << endl;}
    ~Test(){cout << "Test Destroyed" << endl;}
    Test& operator= (Test& test){ k = test.getK(); cout << "Test Assignement Operator called" << endl; return (*this); } // Here 1
    Test(Test& test){k=test.getK();cout << "Test Copy Constructor called" << endl;}
    Sample getK(){return k;} // Here 2
    void setK(Sample& s){k=s;}
    };

int main()
{
    Sample a1(5);
    //Sample a2,a4;
    //a2=a1=a4;
    //Sample a3(a2);
    Test b1(a1);
    Test b2=b1;
    //b2=b1;

    return 0;
    }
```

I am getting below error while compilation:

```
$ g++ -Wall Interview.cpp -o Interview
Interview.cpp: In member function `Test& Test::operator=(Test&)':
Interview.cpp:23: error: no match for 'operator=' in '((Test*)this)->Test::k = Test::getK()()'
Interview.cpp:12: note: candidates are: Sample& Sample::operator=(Sample&)
Interview.cpp: In copy constructor `Test::Test(Test&)':
Interview.cpp:24: error: no match for 'operator=' in '((Test*)this)->Test::k = Test::getK()()'
Interview.cpp:12: note: candidates are: Sample& Sample::operator=(Sample&)
```

When I make changes to `here 2` as - `Sample& getK(){return k;}` it compiles perfectly.

Can someone explain why so?

Also at `here 1` if the function is defined as `Test& operator= (const Test& test){ k = test.getK(); cout << "Test Assignement Operator called" << endl; return (*this); }`

I am getting error-

```
$ g++ -Wall Interview.cpp -o Interview
Interview.cpp: In member function `Test& Test::operator=(const Test&)':
Interview.cpp:23: error: passing `const Test' as `this' argument of `Sample& Test::getK()' discards qualifiers
```

Why so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your copy constructors and assignment operators take non-const lvalue references. For example,

```
Test& operator= (Test& test)
```

This means that temporaries cannot bind as arguments to these constructors/operators. The canonical signature uses `const` references for this reason, and because it makes no sense to mutate the operand:

```
Test& operator= (const Test& test)
                 ^^^^^
```

This will allow binding to temporaries:

```
Test foo () { return Test(); }

Test t0;
t0 = foo();
```

Second, your "getters" need to be `const`, so that they can be called on `const` instances, or via `const` pointers or references:

```
Sample getK() const {return k;}
              ^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

You have defined these operators:

```
Sample& Sample::operator= (Sample& s);
Test& Test::operator= (Test& test);
```

When `a` is any `Sample`,  `a = b;` is the same as `a.operator= (b);`. This is only valid if `b` is a `Sample&`. The return value from `getK` is a temporary `Sample`, and non-const lvalue references (in other words, `Sample&` variables) to temporaries are not permitted  see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565600/how-come-a-non-const-reference-cannot-bind-to-a-temporary-object?rq=1).

If you make `getK` return a lvalue reference to a Sample (`Sample&`), then there is no problem passing it to your assignment operator. Alternatively, if your assignment operator took a const lvalue reference (`const Sample&`) there would be no problem binding it to the temporary object.